# Linksys WRT160NL & ADSL modem/router - WAN port

Tags: router, routing, bridge, adsl, modem

I have a router/modem at ip 192.168.1.254. I also have a linksys router connected to the modem through the **LAN** port.

So right now I have this:

192.168.1.254 <----> 192.168.1.1 <----> PCs (192.168.1.2,etc)

The problem is, I have to assign a fixed ip to my PCs (others work in dhcp, I dont know exactly how), and I also have to configure the gateway and dns server (the modem/router: 192.165.1.254) on each PC.

Can I set up my router to achieve the following:

- Use only dhcp
- No need to configure gateway on PCs
- No need to configure dns server on PCs

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: you should be able to configure your DHCP server to assign permanent leases based on MAC address to certain clients. I have [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com) set up on my WRT54G router to do just this - so certain machines on my network will always have the same IP. Hunt around for the options in your router's firmware, see if they're there :-)

DHCP will also handle DNS and gateway configuration - so you should just be able to enter these values on your DHCP server (you didn't specify which of your routers is handling it) and clients will pick it up automatically. Indeed, that's the primary function of DHCP!

Comment: "also have to configure the gateway and dns server (the modem/router: 192.165.1.254) on each PC.". The router/modem is being used as gateway and dns server.

Comment: Besides, I don't need to have a permanent dhcp lease. I just don't want to configure gateway/dns for each pc.

Comment: You also said you needed some of your machines to have a fixed IP address. You have two choices: manually configure those machines (IP address, DNS, gateway), which you've said you don't want to do; or set up the DHCP server to always give those machines the same IP address (eg a permanent lease) plus DNS and gateway.

Comment: Solved. My router's dhcp was conflicting with my modem/router's dhcp. I disabled one of them.